# IDBCommand Parameters for multi-line insert

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, idbconnection

I want to create a multi-line insert statement along these lines:

```
insert into foo (
    value1,
    value2,
    value3
) values 
( "1", "2", "3"),
( "4", "5", "6"),
( "7", "8", "9");
```

where the number of rows to be inserted is variable.  Is there a way to construct this query using `IDBCommand` parameterization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work fine.

```
IDbCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("insert into foo(col, col2, col3), values");
int parms = 0;

for(int i = 0 ; i<3; i++)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("( @{0}, @{1}, @{2}),", parms, parms + 1, parms + 2);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter((parms++).ToString(), ""));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter((parms++).ToString(), ""));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter((parms++).ToString(), ""));
}
sb.Append(";");
cmd.Parameters;
cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString().Replace(",;", ";");
```

Comment: Is there a limit to how many parameters one can add to a statement?

Comment: I believe that SQL server has a limit in the 200-300 range

Answer (score 0):

There is, to my knowledge, no way to supply a variable number of parameters to an `IDbCommand` at once. You can create the `IDbCommand` once and reuse it for each set of parameter values though:

```
using (IDbCommand command = myConn.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "insert into foo (value1, value2, value3) values (@v1, @v2, @v3)";
    IDbDataParameter param1 = command.CreateParameter() { ParameterName = "@v1" };
    // param2, param3
    foreach (string[] row in records)
    {
        param1.Value = row[0];
        // param2, param3
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Especially within a transaction this should fast if performance was your concern. See [this thread](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/23702.1127596541@sss.pgh.pa.us) for a discussion on performance of one big concatenated insert vs. multiple `ExecuteNonQuery`s in a transaction.

Comment: Won't that require me to make a query per line though?  Blech.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how only the parameter values need to be updated each time, not the entire command. I haven't tested the code, may contain a typo or two.